# Flex component to select month and year only

Tags: apache-flex, custom-controls, components, datechooser

is there a custom component that extends DateChooser that only has the month and year but not the date grid to select a specific day. All i need is the month and year not any specific day. if the month is changed i could use the change event to select the 1st day of that month

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom component using two ComboBoxes and Date instance

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this:

http://riaway.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/flex-month-chooser/